# Azure DevOps: error NU1202 The package Microsoft.AspNetCore.3.1.29 it is not compatible with net 60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0)

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-devops, yaml, pipeline

I am new to working with Azure DevOps. I would like to build this on Azure Pipelines.
My Yaml file looks like this:

```
  - task: JFrogToolsInstaller@1
    displayName: 'Installation de JFrogTools'
    inputs:
      artifactoryConnection: 'JFrog-V2'
      cliInstallationRepo: 'jfrogcliv2'

  - task: JFrogNuGet@1
    displayName: 'JfrogNuget Restore'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      artifactoryConnection: 'JFrog-V2'
      targetResolveRepo: 'nuget-remote'
      solutionPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(Project_name)/xxx.xxx.sln'
      collectBuildInfo: true
      buildName: '$(Build.DefinitionName)'
      buildNumber: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Restore .NET Core'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      feedsToUse: 'select'
      includeNuGetOrg: false

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration Release'
```

Currently getting this error:

```
       Exécution de la tâche "RestoreTask" terminée -- ÉCHEC.
     1>Génération de la cible "Restore" terminée dans le projet "xxxxx.Caching.csproj" -- ÉCHEC.
     1>Génération du projet "C:\DevOpsAgent\_work\385\s\xxxxxx\xxxxx.Caching\xxxx.Caching.csproj" terminée (Restore cible(s)) -- ÉCHEC.

ÉCHEC de la build.

       "C:\DevOpsAgent\_work\385\s\xxxxxx\xxxxx.Caching\xxxxx.Caching.csproj" (Restore cible) (1) ->
       (Restore cible) -> 
         C:\DevOpsAgent\_work\385\s\xxxxx\xxxxx.Caching\xxxxx.Caching.csproj : error NU1202: The package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices 3.1.29 it's not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0). The package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices 3.1.29 supports : netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)

    0 Avertissement(s)
    1 Erreur(s)

Temps écoulé 00:00:01.32
##[debug]Exit code 1 received from tool 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]Packages failed to restore
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Packages failed to restore
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Packages failed to restore
```

I add this task but still failling

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlBR7.png)

Any help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, you seem to be using .NET6. The latest version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices  is 3.1.3 which supports .NET6.  Try [NuGet task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/nuget-command-v2?view=azure-pipelines) and the task below to install NuGet 6.0 :

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Install NuGet >=6.3.0-0'
  inputs:
  versionSpec: '>=6.3.0-0'
  checkLatest: true

You can refer to the similar thread: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27528#issuecomment-1261885440