# IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation + .NET 6 compatibility error - NuGet restore?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, identityserver4, .net-6.0, nuget-package-restore

I am upgrading an existing .NET core 3.1 app, to .NET 6. We were using IdentityServer4 for token validation.

After upgrading to .NET 6, everything appears to work successfully. I can build, launch, and run the app locally. All of the token validation appears to still work just fine.

However, when running a NuGet restore step while trying to build the app in Azure DevOps, I get the following error:

```
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1202: Package IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation 3.0.1 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0). Package IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation 3.0.1 supports: netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0)
```

I am reading conflicting reports, some people say IdentityServer4 should work fine with .NET 6, others say it shouldn't. Other reports seem to think adding different parameters to the NuGet restore step of my .yml script could make this error go away, but I can't seem to figure out how to achieve that.

Does anyone have any insight? Should I be replacing our token validation entirely due to the .NET 6 upgrade? Or is there a way to get NuGet to suppress this issue, since IdentityServer4 seems to be working just fine with .NET 6 anyways?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue today and the solution that worked for me was answered [in this StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74083834/azure-devops-error-nu1202-the-package-microsoft-aspnetcore-3-1-29-it-is-not-com). By default, my Azure DevOps VM was using NuGet 5.X which fails to retrieve net6.0 packages. Installing version 6.5 of NuGet fixed it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Net6.IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation Version="1.0.0" was published April 14th 2023. Upgrading to this package solved the problem for me.